# Transactions in loop

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

In each loop I have to do long running task. I kept each code block per loop in a transaction. My intention is if any loop fails other loops should succeed. If a loop fails, all statements before the exception in that particular loop will not take any effect.I simulate the scenario using the following code:

```
 using(var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var banks = applicationDbContext.Banks.Where(b => b.BankId == 4 || b.BankId == 8);
            foreach(var bank in banks)
            {
                var trn = applicationDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    var bankBranch = applicationDbContext.BankBranchs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BankId == bank.BankId);
                    bankBranch.Name = "sabbir2";
                    if (bank.BankId == 4)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                    applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    trn.Commit();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException exw)
                {
                    trn.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    trn.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

So you see if bankId is 4, it throws an exception & `bankBranch.Name = "sabbir2";` should not take effect. But it is taking effect on the next loop. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not test the bankId at the top of the loop, and if its `4`, skip it?  Why are you using an exception for flow control?  Why are you querying for bank id =4 if you just want to throw an exception?  You know the bank Id before you even begin the transaction...

Comment: before throwing the exception, you should set the entitystate of the not to be modified entry to Unchanged or Detached. Since you retrieved the entry from the context and altered it (set it to modified), it will remain in the context even if you throw an exception. However, throwing exceptions inside and with DbContexts might lead to inconsistent context states which you'll want to avoid, so you should look for another possibility.

Comment: Hi Amy, Actually i just tried simulating my original scenario. Intentionally i check the bankid and throw an exception.What i mean is if in a loop any unhanded exception occurs the code executed in the loop will not take effect in database, next loop will execute as normal if no exception occurs.